# SQL Server 2012 Rows into Columns with varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions, transpose

I am looking for a solution for the following problem, which affects two tables. I already tried to search for the solution, but couldn't find the way to go.

- **single_value**

  > ```
  >    |      docId | siteNo |      siteName | siteAccount | comment | docDate                 | extNo  
  > ---+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-------  
  >  1 | T000000095 | 201060 | Main Location | 92400       | NULL    | 2014-10-31 00:00:00.000 | NULL
  > ```
- **multi_value**

  > ```
  >    |      docId | field_no | row_no | value_char | value_date | value_num
  > ---+------------+----------+--------+------------+------------+-----------  
  >  1 | T000000095 | 60       | 1      | NULL       | NULL       | 250.00
  >  2 | T000000095 | 60       | 2      | NULL       | NULL       | -1.24
  >  3 | T000000095 | 61       | 1      | Positive   | NULL       | NULL
  >  4 | T000000095 | 61       | 2      | Negative   | NULL       | NULL
  >  5 | T000000095 | 62       | 1      | NULL       | NULL       | 90000.00
  >  6 | T000000095 | 62       | 2      | NULL       | NULL       | 688000.00
  > ```

What I need is now an SQL statement which gives me an output like the following one for each row_no of the table multi_value for a specific docId:

```
   |      docId | siteNo |      siteName | siteAccount | comment | docDate                 | extNo | amount | addInfo  | costUnit 
---+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-------|--------+----------+----------  
 1 | T000000095 | 201060 | Main Location | 92400       | NULL    | 2014-10-31 00:00:00.000 | NULL  | 250.00 | Positive | 90000.00 
 2 | T000000095 | 201060 | Main Location | 92400       | NULL    | 2014-10-31 00:00:00.000 | NULL  | -1.24  | Negative | 688000.00
```

It has to list all Information of the table 'single_value' and kind of transpose the values of the table 'multi_value'. The connection between both tables can be achieved via the docId.

The table 'multi_value' is designed in that way, that each field no only allows one specific column to be filled:

- 60 = value_num (amount)
- 61 = value_char (addInfo)
- 62 = value_num (costUnit)

What is the easiest way to achieve that? The table layout cannot be changed. For the transpose of the multi_value I already tried the following, but it doesn't work with the varchar datatype within the column value_char.

```
SELECT row_no
   SUM(case when field_no = 60 then value_num else 0 end) as amount,
   --(case when field_no = 61 then value_char else 0 end) as addInfo,
   SUM(case when field_no = 62 then value_num else 0 end) as costUnit
FROM multi_value
WHERE docId = 'T000000095'
GROUP By
   row_no
```

Many thanks in advance.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but works fine :)

```
SELECT row_no,
   SUM(case when field_no = 60 then value_num else 0 end) as amount,
   case SUM(case
                when field_no = 61 then (
                    case value_char 
                    when 'Positive' then 1 
                    else 2 end
                ) else 0 end
            ) when 1 then 'Positive' else 'Negative' end as addInfo,
   SUM(case when field_no = 62 then value_num else 0 end) as costUnit
FROM multi_value
GROUP By
   row_no
```

---

UPDATE

```
WITH dist as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT value_char
    FROM multi_value
    WHERE value_char is not null
)
, with_no as
(
    select value_char, row_number() over(order by value_char) [no]
    from dist
)
, [raw] as
(
    SELECT m.row_no,
       SUM(case when m.field_no = 60 then m.value_num else 0 end) as amount,
       SUM(case when m.field_no = 61 then d.[no] else 0 end) as addInfo,
       SUM(case when m.field_no = 62 then m.value_num else 0 end) as costUnit
    FROM multi_value m
    LEFT JOIN with_no as d on d.value_char = m.value_char
    GROUP By
       m.row_no
)
SELECT row_no
, amount
, d.value_char as addInfo
, costUnit
FROM [raw] r
LEFT JOIN with_no as d on d.[no] = r.addInfo
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrey. Would work fine, but the content of the column "value_char" contains free text entered by the user and not only 'Positive' or 'Negative'. Sorry, it didn't clearly come out in my question.

Is there any way to consider this?